# How to access Matlab's handle object's sub-property: 'allowedStyles'

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I would like to progmatically access the 'sub-property' of a lineseries object's 'MarkerFaceColor' property called 'allowedStyles'.  This 'sub-property' can be seen in Matlab's inspector, (`inspect(handle)`) by expanding the 'MarkerFaceColor' property row.

I would like to do something like the following or get the equivalent of such a command.
`allowedstyles = get(hh,'MarkerFaceColorAllowStyles');`

Screen shot of Matlab's Inspect window indicating information I seek.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0n19kODkRpSRmJKbkQxakhBRG8/edit?usp=sharing

[image: Inspection Window]

update:

For completeness my final solution for accessing this information via a cellstr was to write the following function.  Thanks to Hoki.

FYI, this information (allowed styles) is useful for a GUI when you want to offer user choices for a property such as MarkerFaceColor, where you don't know the type of graphics object they are modifying.  I populate a listbox with these 'allowedStyles' along with an option to set a colour. Mesh plot 'MarkerFaceColor' allows styles {'none','auto','flat'}, while a lineseries plot has {'none','auto'}.

`function out = getAllowedStyles(hh,tag)
% hh - handle returned from plot, surf, mesh, patch, etc
% tag - the property i.e. 'FaceColor', 'EdgeColor', etc
out = [];
try
    aa = java(handle(hh(1)));
    bb = eval(sprintf('aa.get%s.getAllowedStyles;',tag));
    bb = char(bb.toString);
    bb(1) = []; bb(end) = [];
    out = strtrim(strsplit(bb,','));
end
end`

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Without showing where you got stuck, it is hard to help.

Comment: There is information that is available in Matlab's UI inspect window, that I would like to access on the command line.

Comment: Are you sure it's something that can be modified?

Comment: I don't want to modify it, but just access the 'read-only' property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is indeed *ReadOnly* (or at least I couldn't find the correct way to `set` the property, but it is definitely readable.

You need first to access the handle of the underlying *Java* object, then call the method which query the property:

```
h = plot([0 1]) ;      %// This return the MATLAB handle of the lineseries
hl = java(handle(h)) ; %// this return the JAVA handle of the lineseries
allowedstyles  = hl.getMarkerFaceColor.getAllowedStyles ; %// this return your property :)
```

---

Note that this property is actually an integer index. Your `inspect` windows translate it to a string saying `[none,auto]` while in my configuration even the inspect windows only shows `1`.

If you want the exact string translation of other values than one, you can call only the parent method:

```
hl.getMarkerFaceColor
```

This will display the allowed style in plain text in your console window.

```
ans =
com.mathworks.hg.types.HGMeshColor@28ba43dd[style=none,allowedStyles=[none, auto],red=0.0,green=0.0,blue=0.0,alpha=0.0]
```

If you insist on getting this property as a string progamatically, then you can translate the above using the `toString` method.

```
S = char( hl.getMarkerFaceColor.toString )
S =
com.mathworks.hg.types.HGMeshColor@1ef346e8[style=none,allowedStyles=[none, auto],red=0.0,green=0.0,blue=0.0,alpha=0.0]
```

then parse the result.

Comment: This was a great help.  I feel I simplified the process of getting the string by doing the following,
`aux = h1.getMarkerFaceColor.getAllowedStyles;`
`str = aux.toString;`

Comment: Glad I could help. For me `h1.getMarkerFaceColor.getAllowedStyles` only return a scalar value, so I cannot translate it to a meaningful string. Only way is to parse the string of the result of the parent method.

Comment: Thanks @Hoki I did not know about java handles that's nice. +1

Comment: @Benoit_11, I knew about them (used them in rare cases when Matlab was too limited) but I used to think they were quite more complex to reach (I used some helper function from Matlab Central). I found today's method just by following the `inspect.m` function (good thing it's not a built-in one).